# Beracha achrona on yogurt?

Tags: halacha, blessing, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, eating, dairy

Do you make a boreh nefashot on yogurt according to sepharadim? Is it treated like a liquid, like ice cream, or as a solid? This is in relations to the time needed to eat it. If it's liquid, you wouldn't make boreh nefashot, because you can't eat yogurt that quickly.

Comment: Why would you think it's a solid?

Comment: Why can't you eat yogurt that quickly? Is it too hot? Too cold?

Comment: Let's say that you don't. Do you have 9 minutes or 5 seconds?

Comment: why do you think that being a solid versus a liquid would change yogurt to being a different bracha?

Comment: @Dude read the last part of my question.

Comment: @147zcbm you make a bore nafeshos on both liqued foods. a solid which has a bore nefashos is going to have the same bracha achrona in liquid form.

Comment: You need to drink a liquid in the time it takes to drink a reviit, about 3-4 seconds. Therefore, on things like ice cream, which is considered a liquid, you would never make a beracha ahrona on.

Answer (score 2):

A psak on [din.org](https://din.org.il/2020/09/29/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%98-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95/) says that if yogurt is shaken up and drunk, it's treated like a drink, and if it's eaten, it's treated like food. They based it off of the Shulchan Aruch Harav (Seder Birchas Hanehenin 8:8):

> וְכֵן אֹכֶל שֶׁנִּמּוֹחַ כָּל כָּךְ עַד שֶׁרָאוּי לַשְּׁתִיָּה – יָצָא מִתּוֹרַת אֹכֶל. וְכֵן מַשְׁקֶה שֶׁנִּקְרַשׁ עַד שֶׁרָאוּי לַאֲכִילָה – יָצָא מִתּוֹרַת מַשְׁקֶה, אֲפִלּוּ יֵשׁ בּוֹ טוֹפֵחַ עַל מְנָת לְהַטְפִּיחַ
>
> Similarly, food that has dissolved to the extent that it can be drunk is removed from the halachic category of food. So too, a liquid that has congealed to the extent that it can be eaten is removed from the halachic category of a liquid, even if it is [sufficiently] moist to impart moisture [to something else that touches it].

Rav Ovadia Yosef, however, says in Yabia Omer (pt. 8 siman 25,6):

> ולכאורה נראה שלפי זה האוכל שוקולדה, ואינו לועס אותה בשניו, אלא מוצץ וממחה אותה בפיו, אין לדונו כאוכל, כיון שלא לעס אותה בשניו, ולכן אפי' אם אכל כזית ויותר אינו מברך ברכה אחרונה, ורק אם לעס אותה בשיניו, ואכל כזית בתוך כדי אכילת פרס, מברך ברכה אחרונה.
>
> And it seems that according to this, one who eats chocolate, but doesn't chew it rather sucks it and dissolves it in his mouth, is not considered food, since he didn't chew it with his teeth, therefore even if he ate a *kezayis* or more, he doesn't say a *b'racha achrona*. Only if he chewed it with his teeth and ate a *kezayis* within *achilas p'ras*, does he say a *b'racha achrona*

The same could definitely be said for yogurt, which is never chewed and starts off as a liquid. The minchas Yitzchak (chelek 2 siman 110) also says anything that isn't sucked or chewed is a drink, which would include yogurt.

Therefore, sefardim (at least those who pasken like rav Ovadia) would treat yogurt like a drink. However, CYLOR before doing anything lema'ase